# Jenkins How to Enable OpenID connect plugin

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, google-openid, openid-connect

Currently i am using OpenID 2.0 to authenticate Jenkins. But Now OpenID 2.0 stopped and it is asking to migrate OpenId connect. can anybody help me to resolve this issue.

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 2):

You can use an OpenID Connect plugin in to Jenkins, see: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Google+Login+Plugin, or put a reverse proxy in front of Jenkins that handles OpenID Connect, see: https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc. Both options are also described in the answers provided for: [Google authentication for Gerrit and Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215409/google-authentication-for-gerrit-and-jenkins)